# Using collection to remove duplicate Lists

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have 3 Lists, two of which are duplicates.  I want to store these Lists into one unit, removing all the duplicates, so I was thinking to add each List to a collection.  This is what I tried:

```
List<Integer> coins1 = Arrays.asList(5, 5, 10);
List<Integer> coins2 = Arrays.asList(5, 10, 5);
List<Integer> coins3 = Arrays.asList(10, 10);

coins1.sort((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
coins2.sort((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));
coins3.sort((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));

Collection<List<Integer>> allCoinPossibilities = new TreeSet();

allCoinPossibilities.add(coins1);
allCoinPossibilities.add(coins2);
allCoinPossibilities.add(coins3);
```

I get an error "java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable".  The error makes sense, the Collection doesn't know how to compare each list to disallow duplicates.  Do I need to override a compare method?  If so, How would I do that?  Is this the correct approach to solving this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a `HashSet` instead, so there is no ordering requirement.

Comment: I do not see the need to sort, least of all 3 times. Put one list in a set. The other two check the set. If the value exists then skip, otherwise add to set. The code has a lot of overhead behind curtains

Comment: I tried allPossibilities.contains(coins) rather than sorting, and this approach still adds the duplicates.

Comment: @efekctive You do need to sort them if you want to use `equals`, as it also checks the order of the `List`s.

Comment: Let me get back back with the code. Stuck now

Comment: Done. Check the answer.

Comment: when you say "one unit" do you mean one list with no dups? or 3 lists with no dups in a holding structure?

Comment: One list with no dups.  What I'm really after is the count of unique lists.

Comment: Notice that one list contradicts lists

Comment: To clarify, 1 collection containing no duplicate lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `HashSet` and add everything into that.

At the end you'll be left with just the unique elements

```
List<Integer> coins1 = Arrays.asList(5, 5, 10);
List<Integer> coins2 = Arrays.asList(5, 10, 5);
List<Integer> coins3 = Arrays.asList(10, 10);

Set<Integer> dedupedCollection = new HashSet<Integer>();

dedupedCollection.add(coins1);
dedupedCollection.add(coins2);
dedupedCollection.add(coins3);

return dedupedCollection;
```

then you can `return dedupedCollection;` as the final set with no duplicartes.

Comment: Thanks, this works.  Although I needed new HashSet<List<Integer>>() you answered first.  Now my problem is that my recursion method is very slow, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `HashSet` instead?

`List`s already have a good `hashCode` implementation and a correct `equals` method.

Also, comparing `List`s is not really logically possible - think about comparing two sets of numbers. How do I compare `[2, 3, 8]` with `[1, 7, -2]`?

```
Set<List<Integer>> noDuplicates = new HashSet<>();

noDuplicates.add(coins1);
noDuplicates.add(coins2);
noDuplicates.add(coins3);

//Now there are no duplicate lists.
```

Keep in mind that the lists must also have the same orderings, otherwise `equals` returns false. If you do not want this requirement you can also use a `Set` for your coins.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own `comparator` and pass that as an argument while creating the `TreeSet`, e.g.:

```
class ListComparator implements Comparator<List<Integer>>{

    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> o1, List<Integer> o2) {
        // TODO comparison logic
        return 0;
    }

}

Collection<List<Integer>> allCoinPossibilities = new TreeSet(new ListComparator());
```

Comment: And how would you propose writing a compare method for lists?

Comment: @1blustone we can iterate through lists and compare the elements.

Comment: Would this be quicker than using Hashmap?  Hashmap solved my issue, however, my code is running too slow.  It's using recursion.