# How to remove duplicates from an ArrayLlist of ArrayLists that are composed of custom objects

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, hashset, sublist

I have a recursive function that generates a list of lists that keeps tracks of valid hand combinations for a card game:

```
List<List<HandComponent>> validSCompArrangements = new ArrayList<>();
```

This list is populated by the recursive function successfully but often has duplicate sub-lists (by content but not by not order) that are unavoidable due to the required nature of the function. I wish to remove these duplicate sub-list entries (List<\HandComponent>) so that the above list in the end only features sub-lists that are unique in content, as order does not matter.

Here is the important part of the HandComponent class:

```
public class HandComponent {

    private Type mType;
    private Card mCard; // For runs this is the middle card
    private Source mSource;

    public HandComponent(Type type, Card card, Source source)
    {
        init(type, card, source);
    }

    public enum Type {PAIR, TRIPLE, QUAD, RUN}
    public enum Source {STOLEN, SECRET, EITHER}
...
}
```

A sub-list List should only be considered equal to another sub-list if it contains the same exact HandComponents (i.e. the Type, Card, and Source between components of each list must be the same). Card is another enum defined in another file.

So, if two lists in "validSCompArrangements" are

```
(PAIR,CARD1,STOLEN), (TRIPLE,CARD7,STOLEN), (RUN, CARD8, SECRET)
```

and

```
(TRIPLE,CARD7,STOLEN), (RUN, CARD8, SECRET), (PAIR,CARD1, STOLEN)
```

they should be considered the same since they ultimately contain the same HandComponents even though the order is different and one should be removed so that "validSCompArrangements" only contains that unique list once.

Looking into this I've found bits and pieces on how to solve this problem but nothing that features this combination of a list of lists with custom objects.
One method seems to be to implement a custom Comparator that compares HandComponent instances to use with Collections in order to sort the sub-lists and then another custom Comparator to compare these sorted sub-lists for duplicates, though that seems a tad clunky and I'm not entirely sure how to override the compare method and what kind of return it expects for each comparator I'd need to make. The only other thing I've seen gestured at is that since for my usage the order of both the sub-lists and the main "validSCompArrangements" list itself don't matter, that I should be using Sets and a HashSet to solve this problem instead, I have no idea how to use those to fix this issue, other than that I might need to override the hashCode and equals methods for my HandComponent class, again, not being sure how to do so.

Overall I'm just a bit confused since any example I can manage to find thats remotely related to this usually is talking about just one list of custom objects that contain primatives and not enums, or a list of lists that uses only primatives and no custom objects at all. The fact this is a list of lists of custom objects who's members are enums has me a tad lost on how to go about this.

For example the marked answer in this question: [Using collection to remove duplicate Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330457/using-collection-to-remove-duplicate-lists), that only handles a portion of my problem, doesn't even seem to work for me despite the OP saying it does. Running that code as is, other than changing

```
Set<Integer> dedupedCollection = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

to

```
Set<List<Integer>> dedupedCollection = new HashSet<>();
```

as it was clearly meant to be, produces a collection of 3 entries where the second entry of 5, 10, 5 isn't seen as a duplicate and ignored as the OP suggested it should.

**EDIT:**

So far the closest thing I've found is converting my top-level list to a HashSet using:

```
Set<List<HandComponent>> handSet = new HashSet<>(validSCompArrangments);
```

but this only eliminates duplicate lists if their order is the same (which I am guessing is due to the nature of List's default implementation of "equals()"), while I need it to consider lists that are the same in content but different in order as duplicates also. One way around this would be to use Sets for the HandComponent sub-lists as well since they don't care about order innately, but this would prevent those sets from having duplicate HandComponents which I do need to be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working best for me was to implement the "equals()" method for my HandComponent class as suggested by Jiajie Xu, along with the "hashCode()" method automatically generated by Android Studio by using the option in the context menu or Alt + Insert:

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    HandComponent that = (HandComponent) o;
    return mType == that.mType &&
            mCard == that.mCard &&
            mSource == that.mSource;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(mType, mCard, mSource);
}
```

I then also made the class implement the Comparable interface for use with the Collections class and specified the sort order priority of HandComponent instances within the "compareTo()" method like so:

```
 @Override
public int compareTo(@NonNull HandComponent other) {

    // Check Type first
    int compareResult = mType.compareTo(other.mType);
    if(compareResult == 0)
    {
        // Check Card second
        compareResult = mCard.compareTo(other.mCard);
        if(compareResult == 0)
        {
            // Check Source last
            compareResult = mSource.compareTo(other.mSource);
        }
    }

    return compareResult;
}
```

Since the default implementation of Comparable for List requires list order to be the same in order to return "true" when comparing two lists, I needed to sort my List of Lists every time I wanted to remove duplicates, which was perfectly fine as I benefited from the organization later on.

Ultimately, this allowed me remove the duplicates from my List of Lists of custom objects  by first making sure the sub-lists of HandComponent were all sorted and then creating a HashSet of the top-level list.

```
List<List<HandComponent>> unsortedList = new ArrayList<>();
... // Populate list

for(int i = 0; i < unsortedList.size(); i++)
{
    Collections.sort(unsortedList.get(i));
}

Set<List<HandComponent>> sortedDeDupedSet = new HashSet<>(unsortedList);

// Convert back to list since I need order to matter again later on
List<List<HandComponenet>> sortedDeDupedList = new ArrayList<>(sortedDeDupedSet);
```

This correctly removes duplicates from the top-level list now that I have properly implemented the "equals()" and "hashCode()" methods, as well as sorted the lists before hand with "compareTo()" by leveraging List's default Comparable implementation. Having to use a for loop to sort the lists themselves since I'm restricted to Java 7 does feel a little bad, but like I said before ultimately it was useful to have the lists sorted for other purposes and a lot of time and code is still saved from using a HashSet, versus the nested for loops that would be required to compare each List entry manually.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you just need to implement `equals` :)

I've provided you how to implement equals method in the `HandComponent` class and how to use HashSet to getting only the combinations without duplicates.

I've implemented it in Java 8, you can also try to change it using for loop if you want :)

Here is the `equals` implementation of `HandComponent

```
public class HandComponent {

public enum Type {PAIR, TRIPLE, QUAD, RUN}

public enum Source {STOLEN, SECRET, EITHER}

public enum Card {ACE, ONE, TWO, TRHEE}

private Type type;
private Card card;
private Source source;

public HandComponent(Type type, Card card, Source source) {
    this.type = type;
    this.card = card;
    this.source = source;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof HandComponent)) {
        return false;
    }
    HandComponent handComponent = (HandComponent) o;

    if (type != handComponent.type) {
        return false;
    }

    if (card != handComponent.card) {
        return false;
    }

    if (source != handComponent.source) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "HandComponent=[" + String.join(", ", Arrays.asList(type.toString(), card.toString(), source.toString())) + "]";
}
}
```

And below you can see how you can use it

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Creating 2 hand components
    HandComponent handComponent1 = new HandComponent(HandComponent.Type.PAIR, HandComponent.Card.ACE, HandComponent.Source.STOLEN);
    HandComponent handComponent2 = new HandComponent(HandComponent.Type.QUAD, HandComponent.Card.TRHEE, HandComponent.Source.EITHER);

    // 2 combinations with the same card, but different order => they are the same
    List<HandComponent> firstCombination = Arrays.asList(handComponent1, handComponent2);
    List<HandComponent> secondCombination = Arrays.asList(handComponent2, handComponent1);

    // Mixing 2 combinations together
    List<List<HandComponent>> combinations = Arrays.asList(firstCombination, secondCombination);

    // printing the mix
    System.out.println("Before: " + combinations);

    // removing duplicates
    List<ArrayList<HandComponent>> collect = combinations.stream() // having a stream of list<HandComponent>
            .map(HashSet::new) // converting to HashSet, which mean there won't be duplicate in the combinations.
            .distinct()        // getting only the distinct combinations
            .map(ArrayList::new) // reconverting to array list
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collecting them as list

    // result without duplicates
    System.out.println("After: " + collect);

    // You can now implement it with loop and no java 8 :)
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code. This is pretty close, but not quite exactly what I needed. Your example does get rip of the duplicate sub-lists as I require, but also removes duplicate HandComponent objects within each sub-list that I actually wish to maintain. So for example if I add "handComponent1" to the end of "firstCombination" and "secondCombination", so that they are still identical in content and just different in order, the output of "collect" still shows: "[[HandComponent=[PAIR, ACE, STOLEN], HandComponent=[QUAD, TRHEE, EITHER]]]" showing that the second "handComponent1" are gone.

Comment: I tried removing ".map(HashSet:new)" from the stream pipeline since your comment suggested that this is what was causing this unwanted behavior, but this also stopped the code from removing the duplicate sub-lists, so I'm not sure how to fix this issue. Otherwise, it seems like the "distinct()" function is the core of what I'm after, though I'm not at all familiar with Java 8 and must use 7 due to the android version I'm developing for, so I'm looking into how to perform its functionality in Java 7.

Comment: One solution would be wrapping the List<HandComponent> into a class. For example a class called HandComponentCombination, which only has a field of List<HandComponent> and then the class would overwrite the equals.